# How to detect a website is a squatter?

Tags: java, algorithm, web-crawler, feature-detection

I'm trying to detect whether certain websites are "valid" websites. Some things that make a website invalid:

- Gives back bad status codes
- Page content is empty
- Website is a squatter (for example, the url points to a GoDaddy page, or any page that says come register this domain!)

I'm trying to figure out how to detect whether a website is a squatter. I'm using Java if that matters. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound like a good task for [Machine Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) in my opinion.

Collect a sample of websites, some of them are 'squatters' and some of them are not (this is called the train set).

Use the [bag of words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) model, or the [tf-idf model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) (or any other model) as your features-space, and train a classifier using some [supervised learning algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning) ([SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine), [decision trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning),...).

On run time, use your classifier to determine if a website is a squatter or not.

[Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) is a java library that implements many Machine Learning algorithm, and might help you.